# What does it mean that 'OOP languages are organized around graphs'?

Tags: sql, oop

In [Learning SQL the Hard Way](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/introduction.html), the author says:

> OOP languages are organized around graphs, but SQL wants to only
>   return tables

What does it mean for an OOP language to be organized around a graph?  Does this refer to data being stored in specific memory addresses?

Comment: By graph, I think they mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type), a bunch of nodes and connections. Whereas SQL sources and _Results_ are generally table-like (rows and columns). I doubt it means anything as concrete as memory addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nick.McDermaid comments above, the relevant sense of *graph* is [the abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29).

In an object-oriented language, the "object graph" consists of objects and the "has-a" relationships between them. For example, a `Person` object might have a field of type `Collection<Address>`, in which case the object graph would include the relationship from the person to all of his/her addresses.

The sentence immediately following your quotation is, "If SQL returned a nested data structure then this wouldn't be a problem." If you select from a `PERSON` table, you will not automatically get all of the corresponding rows from `ADDRESS`. You can do a `JOIN`, of course, but then the result-set will include one copy of the `PERSON` row for each of its corresponding `ADDRESS` rows. So you have to do some translation work, after getting your query results, to create the object graph that you would like to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Relations between object represents [graph](https://www.google.ru/search?q=object%20relations%20graph&tbm=isch).